# Which is more appropriate to do data filter: front end or back end

Tags: javascript, server-side

For starters--I am a "noob" to programming, so just learning how things work and reaching out to the community for help.

But...what I want to know is:

I have a web application I want to build, and one of the two primary user interfaces is effectively a calendar product.  Each calendar item has 8 category items associated with it, with each category having around 5 options. I want my calendar to have a robust event filtering system, preferably with user interactions with the filters not requiring a page reload.

Given this information, can Javascript do the filtering on the front end, and is that the most appropriate way of filtering versus having the server-side deliver/re-deliver events based on filters selected/de-selected?  So for example, if there were 50 total events (assuming no applied filters), I would have the server-side language query/load all 50, and then hand off to JS, which would run the filtering logic and display/not-display as appropriate?

Comment: Filtering 50 events should be trivial, so preloading them all and filtering on the client is reasonable. But once you get to thousands of events, you'll prefer server-side filtering because it will push less data to the client and provide results faster.

Comment: as said it depends on the data volume , as far as thumb of rule goes i would prefer working on larger volume on data at backend, and less volume at the front end.

Comment: It does not only depend on the data volume, but also whether the app should support non-JS browsers, where the event data is generated (right by the user?) and whether events are user-specific or not.

Answer (score 0):

you can try cross-filter , which is best tool for data filtering from front-end.

you can read the details from link below:

[crossfilter in github](http://square.github.io/crossfilter/)